# Customised elasticsearch sorting

Tags: elasticsearch

I want records in a customized sort from the elastic search. let me give you an example.

I have product data with the brand assigned to the product.
If I have 4 brands
Brand 1 having 2 products
Brand 2 having 4 products
Brand 3 having 1 product
Brand 4 having 2 product

Then it should fetch as below

Product of brand 1
product of brand 2
product of brand 3
product of brand 4
product of brand 1
product of brand 2
product of brand 4
product of brand 2
product of brand 2

I have records in elasticsearch as below

records

```
{
   _id: 602fd36ca7b0dabd31a5f7f9,
   name: "product 1",
   brand_id: 602fd36ca7b0dabd31a5f7fb,
   priority: 2
},
{
    _id: 602fd36ca7b0dabd31a5f7fa,
   name: "product 2",
   brand_id: 602fd36ca7b0dabd31a5f7fb,
   priority: 2
},
{
    _id: 602fd36ca7b0dabd31a1f7fb,
   name: "product 3",
   brand_id: 602fd36ca7b0dabd31a5f7fb,
   priority: 2
},
{
    _id: 602fd36ca7b0dabd31a5f7fc,
   name: "product 4",
   brand_id: 5fe128f2ab6506780bd8fd3a,
   priority: 1
},
{
    _id: 602fd36ca7b0dabd31a5f7fd,
   name: "product 5",
   brand_id: 5fe128f2ab6506780bd8fed8,
   priority: 6
},
{
    _id: 602fd36ca7b0dabd31a5f7fe,
   name: "product 6",
   brand_id: 5fe128f2ab6506780bd8fc49,
   priority: 3
},
{
    _id: 602fd36ca7b0dabd31a5f7ff,
   name: "product 7",
   brand_id: 5fe128f2ab6506780bd8fed8,
   priority: 6
},
{
    _id: 602fd36ca7b0dabd31a5f7a1,
   name: "product 8",
   brand_id: 602fd36ca7b0dabd31a5f7fb,
   priority: 2
},
{
    _id: 602fd36ca7b0dabd32a5f7a1,
   name: "product 9",
   brand_id: 5fe128f2ab6506780bd8fd3a,
   priority: 1
}
```

expected sequence as per below

```
{
    _id: 602fd36ca7b0dabd31a5f7fc,
   name: "product 4",
   brand_id: 5fe128f2ab6506780bd8fd3a,
   priority: 1
},
{
   _id: 602fd36ca7b0dabd31a5f7f9,
   name: "product 1",
   brand_id: 602fd36ca7b0dabd31a5f7fb,
   priority: 2
},
{
    _id: 602fd36ca7b0dabd31a5f7fe,
   name: "product 6",
   brand_id: 5fe128f2ab6506780bd8fc49,
   priority: 3
},
{
    _id: 602fd36ca7b0dabd31a5f7fd,
   name: "product 5",
   brand_id: 5fe128f2ab6506780bd8fed8,
   priority: 6
},
{
    _id: 602fd36ca7b0dabd32a5f7a1,
   name: "product 9",
   brand_id: 5fe128f2ab6506780bd8fd3a,
   priority: 1
},
{
    _id: 602fd36ca7b0dabd31a5f7fa,
   name: "product 2",
   brand_id: 602fd36ca7b0dabd31a5f7fb,
   priority: 2
},
{
    _id: 602fd36ca7b0dabd31a5f7ff,
   name: "product 7",
   brand_id: 5fe128f2ab6506780bd8fed8,
   priority: 6
},
{
    _id: 602fd36ca7b0dabd31a1f7fb,
   name: "product 3",
   brand_id: 602fd36ca7b0dabd31a5f7fb,
   priority: 2
},
{
    _id: 602fd36ca7b0dabd31a5f7a1,
   name: "product 8",
   brand_id: 602fd36ca7b0dabd31a5f7fb,
   priority: 2
}
```

Comment: Huh? What's the pattern there?

Comment: I want to pick one records from each brand one by one